# writing to an ioport resulting in segfaults

Tags: io, arm, embedded-linux, ports

I'm writing for an atmel at91sam9260 arm 9 cored single board computer [glomation gesbc9260]

Using `request_mem_region(0xFFFFFC00,0x100,"name"); //port range runs from fc00 to fcff`

that works fine and shows up in `/proc/iomem`

then i try to write to the last bit of the port at fc20 with

`writel(0x1, 0xFFFFFC20);`

and i segfault...specifically "unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address fffffc20."

I'm of the mind that i'm not allocating the right memory space...

any helpful insight would be great...

Answer (score 3):

You need to ioremap the mem region you requested. ioremap maps a virtual address to a physical one.
writel works with virtual addresses, not with physical ones.

```
/* request mem_region */
...

base = ioremap(0xFFFFFC00, 0x100);
if(base == NULL)
    release_mem_region(...);
/* now you can use base */
writel(0x1, base + 20)
...
```

What you probably need is to write your driver as a platform_driver, and declare a platform device in your board_file

An example of a relatively simple platform_driver can be found [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpio/timbgpio.c?v=2.6.34)
In fact, navigating through the kernel sources using lxr is probably the best way to learn how to
stuff like this.

Comment: awesome - that sorted me out :) thaks

Comment: Should `iowrite32` be used instead?

Comment: Is the `request_mem_region` still required as well as the `ioremap` if another driver has already mapped it into virtual memory?

Comment: @IanVaughan : Then one drivers depends on the other. What happens if the first driver is unloaded / releases it's resources, and the second tries to acess to memory that is not mapped anymore ? I think it deserves a question, and the context of why two driver share the same resource.